# How can I make the score equal to the elapsed time playing the game( in seconds) in spritekit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Okay, so I tried the orbivoid tutorial, however I want that the elapsed time (in seconds) would be the score of the player and not the number of enemy respawned. I tried so many things with regards to NSTimer, NSTimeInterval and CFTimeInterval but needless to say, I failed. Can somebody help me with regards to this -- What code to add, tips or something? BTW, this is the GameScene.m in the orbivoid tutorial.
Thank you in advance!

```
 @implementation GameScene
    {
        BOOL _dead;
        SKNode *_player;
        NSMutableArray *_enemies;
        SKLabelNode *_scoreLabel;
    }


    -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];


        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;


        _enemies = [NSMutableArray new];

        _player = [SKNode node];
        SKShapeNode *circle = [SKShapeNode node];

circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(-10, -10, 20, 20)].CGPath;`
        circle.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        circle.glowWidth = 5;

        SKEmitterNode *trail = [SKEmitterNode orb_emitterNamed:@"Trail"];
        trail.targetNode = self;
        trail.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(circle.frame), CGRectGetMidY(circle.frame));
        _player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
        _player.physicsBody.mass = 100000;
        _player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionPlayer;
        _player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionEnemy;




        [_player addChild:trail];

        _player.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);

        [self addChild:_player];


    }
    return self;
}

    - (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(spawnEnemy) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
        }

    -(void)spawnEnemy
    {
        [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Spawn.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]];
        SKNode *enemy = [SKNode node];

        SKEmitterNode *trail = [SKEmitterNode orb_emitterNamed:@"Trail"];
        trail.targetNode = self;
        trail.particleScale /= 2;
        trail.position = CGPointMake(10, 10);
        trail.particleColorSequence = [[SKKeyframeSequence alloc] initWithKeyframeValues:@[


[SKColor redColor],
                                                                                        [SKColor colorWithHue:0.1 saturation:.5 brightness:1 alpha:1],
                                                                                        [SKColor redColor],
                                                                                        ] times:@[@0, @0.02, @0.2]];




        [enemy addChild:trail];
    enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:6];
    enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionEnemy;
    enemy.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;

        enemy.position = CGPointMake(50, 50);

    [_enemies addObject:enemy];
    [self addChild:enemy];

    if(!_scoreLabel) {
    _scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Courier-Bold"];

    _scoreLabel.fontSize = 200;
    _scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
    CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    _scoreLabel.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:1 alpha:0.5];
    [self addChild:_scoreLabel];
    }
    _scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", _enemies.count];



    // Next spawn
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction waitForDuration:5],
        [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnEnemy) onTarget:self],
        ]]];
        }


    -(void)dieFrom: (SKNode*)killingEnemy
    {
    _dead = YES;

    SKEmitterNode *explosion = [SKEmitterNode orb_emitterNamed:@"Explosion"];
    explosion.position = _player.position;
    [self addChild:explosion];

    [explosion runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Explosion.wav" waitForCompletion:NO],
        [SKAction waitForDuration:0.4],
        [SKAction runBlock:^{
            // TODO: Revove these more nicely
            [killingEnemy removeFromParent];
            [_player removeFromParent];
        }],
        [SKAction waitForDuration:0.4],
        [SKAction runBlock:^{
            explosion.particleBirthRate = 0;
            }],
            [SKAction waitForDuration: 1.2],

        [SKAction runBlock:^{
            ORBMenuScene *menu = [[ORBMenuScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
[self.view presentScene:menu transition:[SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:0.4]];
        }],
        ]]];

}


    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    }

    -(void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [_player runAction:[SKAction moveTo:[[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self] duration:.01]];
    }

    -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
    {
        CGPoint playerPos = _player.position;

        for(SKNode *enemyNode in _enemies)
        {
            CGPoint enemyPos = enemyNode.position;

            /* Uniform speed: */
            CGVector diff = TCVectorMinus(playerPos, enemyPos);
            CGVector normalized = TCVectorUnit(diff);
            CGVector force = TCVectorMultiply(normalized, 4);

            [enemyNode.physicsBody applyForce:force];
        }

        _player.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake (0, 0);


        }
    -(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
    {
        if(_dead)
                return;

        [self dieFrom:contact.bodyB.node];
        contact.bodyB.node.physicsBody = nil;
        }

    @end
```

Comment: Already outdated?  Did you try the solution you found recommending `NSTimer` and `NSTimeInterval`?  How are you keeping track of time?  This question is far too broad and doesn't explicitly state what has been tried and what specific problems the user has come up against.

Comment: Yes I tried the solution which recommends NSTimer and NSTimeInterval. But I think It was supposed to be for a ViewController(UI) that's why it didn't work after trying to implement it in a SKScene.

Comment: You need to spend some time improving your question.  You haven't shown us what you tried and haven't explained why it didn't work.  What was the actual result of what you tried and what was the expected results?  And don't tell me in comments.  Update the question to include all of this information.  You also need to remove the bottom question (regarding spawning monsters).  That needs to be a different question.  It makes this question way, way, way to broad.  (And if you do post that as a different question, you need to include details about how you're spawning monsters.)

Comment: SKScene has an update method, increment an int var ever time it is called. NSTimer is no good for SK because it won't stop firing if game is paused or game speed changes.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, that's some odd advice. `NSTimer` is just fine for this. You simply have to pause the timer when the user pauses the game.

Comment: but you have no guarantee when in the update cycle the timer fires: before, between or after update: didEvaluateActions and didSimulatePhysics. For multiple timers you also have no control over in which order they fire.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the suggestions. I updated my question so that it would be easier for those of you who wants to help, and of course for those who needs the same answers as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Simple Version: create a score integer (_block needed because you're going to use it in a block)

```
__block int score123=0;
```

Run an action that increases your integer then waits 1.0 seconds before doing it again. This sequence repeats forever. Give the action the key "scoreIncrease" so you can stop it later.

```
SKAction *scoreIncrease = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction runBlock:^{ score123++; }],[SKAction waitForDuration:1.0f]]]];
[self runAction:scoreIncrease withKey:@"scoreIncrease"];
```

When you want to stop the counting, use this:

`[self removeActionForKey:@"scoreIncrease"];`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But after trying this, the score label frame in the middle of the screen just turns to black. I don't know why. Am I to remove something from my previous code like the if (!score_label) { or something and where exactly should I add them? I still placed the code you gave me in the spawnEnemy method. Is it wrong?? Thanks again!

Comment: This code won't affect your scoreLabel in any way. The first part goes in "@implementation GameScene", the second part goes in "-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {", and the last bit goes in "-(void)dieFrom: (SKNode*)killingEnemy".